# What is the proper term for the opposite of "graph pruning"?

Tags: graph-theory

In my understanding, "graph pruning" may refer to a process of removing a vertex (or more) of a graph.

Suppose I want to add new vertex to the same graph, what is the proper term for such process?

Does "graph inclusion" correct? Or is it "graph appending"?

Thank you.

Comment: How about "augmentation"?